# Meteor helper not Reactive

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have the following helper:

```
target:function(){
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Meteor.userId()});
        if (user) {

            var targetId = user.profile.target;
            var target = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:targetId});
            if (target) {
                console.log(target);
               var targetInfo = target.profile.lastName + ", " + target.profile.firstName;
               return targetInfo;
               }
               else{
                return;
               }

        }

        else{
            return;
        }

    },
```

It should return the target first and last name, but the problem is that I should refresh the page in order to display them.

That is the publish function

```
Meteor.publish("users", function () {
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['admin'])) {
        return Meteor.users.find({"roles":{ $nin: ['admin'] }});
    } else {
        return Meteor.users.find({"roles":{ $nin: ['admin'] }} , {fields: {_id:1, 'profile.firstName': 1, 'profile.lastName': 1 }});
    }
});
```

Comment: If the page works on refresh, typically that means there's a reactivity issue with the publisher and not the helper. If autopublish isn't still on, can you show how you are publishing the users?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I actually fixed it, the problem was that I had to exclude fields from the subscription, not to include

Comment: Yep, also be careful about using sub-field projections. They usually result in something you don't want. See the "merge box" section of [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Comment: I will definitely have a look at this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Session to make it reactive.

```
  Session.set("data", targetInfo);
  ...
  return  Session.get("data");
```